# menue with css transitions doesnt work like expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, transition

I have a menue made with css transitions and css.
This is build like this: In a main div of an topic, is another div with the topics content. When i want to show this, (onclick) i add an class to the main div, which contains     height: auto;
Actually its working like excepting, BUT before setting to the right height, the div is setting his height to 0. Why does it do this? Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Heres the code:

```
html:
<div class="class1" onclick="this.className='class1 class2'">
    test topic: (click here)
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

css:
class1{
    height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 2s;
}
class2{
    height: auto;
}
```

Heres a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ML98q/5/).

And here the [homepage](http://www.castlenightmare.bplaced.de/index.php). (to test it, the menue is right...)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UpuDU/  (you can make better with jquery)

Comment: height: auto dosen't work with transition. Use value with px(200px, 400px)

Comment: but then i need a fixed value for every box...

Comment: then you need to use JQ slide function

Comment: Your homepage is returning a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: actually not. which browser? which system?

Answer (score 0):

This has been covered before: [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto), [CSS transition auto height not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938460/css-transition-auto-height-not-working), [CSS3 transition to height auto goes to height 0 first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922076/css3-transition-to-height-auto-goes-to-height-0-first), http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/

It looks like the work around is to use max-height instead of height, and for your transition set a max-height rather than height:auto. Just beware that if you set a max-height much larger than the height will ever be, the timing of your transition will be thrown off.

```
.class2{
    max-height:200px;
}
```

Demo using your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jag96/SwWXm/

Comment: the timing is completely wrong with this... the transition "back" is delayed by 2 seconds... Anyway i have another solution: every menue div has an special attribute, called "px", looks like this:

<div class="..." px="115">

this value im getting with javascript, and setting the height to this.